# Simplify points in KML using regex

Tags: regex, maps, kml

I am trying to cut down the file size of a kml file I have.

The coordinates for the polygons are this accurate:

```
-113.52106535153605,53.912817815321503,0.
```

I am not very good with regex, but I think it would be possible to write one that selects the eight characters before the commas. I'd run a search and replace so the result would be

```
-113.521065,53.9128178,0.
```

Any regex experts out there think this is possible?

Comment: In which language or which tool do you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that might work. Replaces 8 chars and the coma with a coma: s/(.{8}),/,/g;

> echo "-113.52106535153605,53.912817815321503,0." | sed 's/.\{8\},/,/'

So you can cat the file you have to a sed command like this:

> cat file.kml | sed 's/.\{8\},/,/' > newfile.kml

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\d{8}(?=,)
```

and replace with an empty string

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v7k0)

Answer (score 0):

I Just had to do the same thing. This is perl instead of sed, but it will look for a string of eight uninterrupted digits and then replace any number of uninterrupted digits after that with nothing. It worked great.

cat originalfile.kml | perl -pe 's/(?<=\d{8})\d*//g' > shortenedfile.kml